# C# Преобразование массива строк в массив байт

Tags: c#, массивы, crc

Открываю текстовый файл посредством File.ReadAllLines. Изменяю случайным образом одну из строк и сохраняю обратно в файл с помощью File.WriteAllLines.

Затем (о ужас!) опять открываю этот же файл как массив байт File.ReadAllBytes считаю от этого массива байт контрольную сумму (CRC16) и если она меня не устраивает повторяю всё заново (эдакий брутфорс по подбору контрольной суммы файла).

Можно ли как-то преобразовывать получаемый массив строк в массив байт для того чтобы находу посчитать от него контрольную сумму без промежуточного сохранения на жесткий диск?

Answer (score 3):

Вы конечно делаете что-то непонятное для меня, не понимаю, зачем вам работать со строками для подсчета контрольной суммы. 
Разумеется, если вы знаете кодировку вашего файла, то вы можете преобразовать строку в массив байт и обратно с помощью класса [Encoding](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.text.encoding(v=vs.110).aspx). Класс позволяет получить кодировку символов, а уже с помощью методов GetBytes и GetString получить массив байт из строки и строку из массива байт соответственно. Пример

```
string s = "Petya";
byte[] b = Encoding.GetEncoding(1251).GetBytes(s);
s = Encoding.GetEncoding(1251).GetString(b);
```

Список поддерживаемых кодовых страниц найдете по указанной выше ссылке.

Также стоит отметить, что класс имеет ряд вспомогательных свойств для часто-используемых кодовых страниц, и для них можно писать более короткий и более читабельный код. Например, для кодовой страницы UTF-8 можно написать

```
string s = "Petya";
byte[] b = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(s);
s = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(b);
```

P.S Вызывая  [File.ReadAllLines](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/s2tte0y1(v=vs.110).aspx), вы вероятнее всего открываете файл с кодировкой UTF-8. Соответственно, чтобы преобразовать строку в массив байт, вы можете написать так, как указано в примере выше

Comment: Спасибо, Алексей. В итоге я собираю массив строк в одну строку и уже из неё, используя Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes, получаю массив байт. Стало значительно лучше.